# Similar Record count for Different User Sessions

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, user login is through sessions. There exists a dashboard that displays ticket count assigned to each user. This count is initiated through an SQL Procedure.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Usp_GetTicketCountByUserID]
    @UserID int
AS
BEGIN
    Select  AssignToAdmin,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'A' then 1 else NULL END) openCount,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'C' then 2 else NULL END) ClosedCount
    from AssignedRoles
    where AssignToAdmin = @UserID
    GROUP BY AssignToAdmin
END
GO
```

When I execute the procedure from SQL I get the correct results, however from the application it displays zero(0). I noticed that when I remove the where clause it displays a similar count for all users which should not be the case.

Controller:

```
var x = _ITimesheet.GetTimeSheetsCountByUserID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]));

if (x != null)
{
    ViewBag.MyCall = x.OpenCount;
    ViewBag.ClosedTicket = x.ClosedCount;
}
else
{
    ViewBag.MyCall = 0;
    ViewBag.ClosedTicket = 0;
}
```

Class

```
public DisplayViewModel GetTimeSheetsCountByUserID(int UserID)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TSC"].ToString()))
    {
        var param = new DynamicParameters();
        param.Add("@UserID", UserID);
        return con.Query<DisplayViewModel>("Usp_GetTicketCountByUserID", param, null, true, 0, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Any help on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: The only way it can be returning a different result is if you are passing in a different `@UserID`, after all thats the only variable in the system. Unless you are connected to a different database, but I'm assuming that isn't the case.

Comment: the database is one and the sessions are very different.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently I inappropriately assigned that class [UserID] instead of [AdminID]. This is because I have various sessions based on the User Role.